# No response from a click event in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an app in Android Studio, which has a Main activity and a Settings activity. I am using the starter code from the [PunchThrough BLE tutorial](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/). To go straight to the GitHub repo, click [here](https://github.com/PunchThrough/ble-starter-android).

**Expectation:** In the Settings activity, I want the text in the LinearLayout to be clickable, and I want an action to be performed upon being clicked. In this case, I am trying to get a Toast message to pop up which describes which item was clicked.

**Reality:** When I land on the Settings activity page and try to click on the items in the LinearLayout (whether it's a Button view or a TextView in the XML), I don't get any response from the click. When I make the items Button views, I can see that the button is being clicked, but nothing happens. When I make the items TextViews, I can't see anything happening at all.

I would like to know if there is something preventing my Toast messages from being launched on the click event.

*In case it is helpful*, here is the relevant code from my Main activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        settings_button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Settings::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
   }
```

Here is the code for my Settings activity.

```
class Settings : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.settings) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        weather_data_textview.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Shows weather data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        remove_device_textview.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Shows remove device dialogue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        pool_maintenance_tips_textview.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Shows pool maintenance tips", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

}
```

And finally, here is the Settings activity XML.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_data_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/weather_data_label"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remove_device_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/remove_device_label"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pool_maintenance_tips_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/pool_maintenance_tips_label"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Disclaimer:** I *would* include a list of sources I've already looked at for this problem, but I have probably turned every single link purple on Google in my pursuit of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overrode the wrong overload of `onCreate()`. You used the one with PersistableBundle, which according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)) is only used when `persistableMode` is set to `persistAcrossReboots`.

As such, your `onCreate()` function is not getting called at all.

Change your override to the `onCreate()` with only one argument:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //...
```